# Python PIL: wrong opening of image sequence

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, canopy

I've encountered a strange problem with PIL.
I open image stacks taken with a CCD camera, and then save them in a numpy matrix.
I wrote a little function to do that.
I noticed that, when i analyze the time signal in some particular pixels, negative values appear, but this is crazy because I'm sure I have light intensity images that can't display less than 0.
Here is my function:

```
def readStack (filename, stack, extension = '.tif'):   
image = Img.open(filename+extension)
M,N = image.size[1], image.size[0]
matrix = np.zeros((M,N,stack))
for k in range (stack):
    if (k%1000 == 0): print k,'; ' 
    image.seek(k)
    loaded = image.load()
    for i in range(M):
       for j in range (N):
           matrix[i,j,k] = np.abs(loaded[j,i])
return matrix
```

I tried to correct this issue forcing the program with "np.abs", but it seems too strange for me to be forced to do this.

Here is a sample signal: the graph is plotted with matplotlib, the black one was taken with ImageJ and shows the correct profile:
[image]

This happens sometimes, with a peak value that becomes negative. But the two signals, referred to the same pixel, are the same in every other value.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: are you using PIL or Pillow? Which version? Also, can you post some example data that illustrates the problem, so we can try and reproduce it?

Comment: Does the error occur only for values above 32,768?

Comment: Yes, it seems it happens only when there is a big peak value. I'm using PIL. Here is a link to a google drive folder with:
- .tif stack images
- part of the program i used.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8B9d2LsyXlcbTlyMlNUYmlzNFk&usp=sharing